# How to find id of html element using php

Tags: php, html

This is not a duplicated question. I have a html tag that has id.
I want to find value of id using php. How to do that? Is it possible?
For example:

```
<p id="par"><?php /* find value of id */ ?></p>
```

I want to find "par" using php.
Please answer exactly, for example some people say use html-dom but they don't know how.

Comment: when you want find id. if its on click then use jquery

Comment: Are you sure you want to use PHP for this? If you are, then yes, DOM is a good tool - http://htmlparsing.com/php.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not.

PHP is executed on the server, not in the browser. You could try to parse the PHP file for the value, but the value is either a constant or it is already the result of a PHP expression, so there is no point.